# How to substitute items firebase flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, null

I'm developing a Flutter app, which uses Firebase as a backend. In my Cloud Firestore I have two collecions, football (it contains a single document) and upcomingteams.

The fields of the document in football:

  -String currentTeam1
  -String currentTeam2
  -String upcomingTeam1
  -String upcomingTeam2
  -int team1Score
  -int team2Score

The fields of the documents in upcomingTeams:

  -Timestamp createdAt
  - String upcomingTeam1
  - String upcomingTeam2
  In my app, I have a button, which sets the scores at the end of the match to zero. After it sets the scores, I want it to do the following:
- In the football document put the value of upcomingTeam1 into currentTeam1, and the same with team 2

  From the upcomingTeams, copy the teams and put the values into the football documents upcomingTeam1 and upcomingTeam2 fields

To achieve this I believe the first step is to get the upcomingTeam1 and upcomingTeam2 from the football document. For this I wrote the following function which is assigned in the onTap property of the respective button:

```
void _nextMatch() {
    UpcomingMatch upcomingMatch;
    Firestore.instance
        .collection('football')
        .document("cMrD3OoOsWuzJmzlpfsr")
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        upcomingMatch = UpcomingMatch(
            documentSnapshot.data["nextTeam1"].toString(),
            documentSnapshot.data["nextTeam2"].toString());
        print(documentSnapshot.data["nextTeam1"].toString());
        print(documentSnapshot.data["nextTeam2"].toString());
      }
    });
    if (upcomingMatch.upcomingTeam1.isNotEmpty && upcomingMatch.upcomingTeam2.isNotEmpty) {
      Firestore.instance
          .collection("football")
          .document("cMrD3OoOsWuzJmzlpfsr")
          .updateData({
        "currentTeam1": upcomingMatch.upcomingTeam1,
        "currentTeam2": upcomingMatch.upcomingTeam2,
      });
    }
  }
```

But for this I get the following error:

```
I/flutter ( 8687): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
I/flutter ( 8687): The getter 'upcomingTeam1' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 8687): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 8687): Tried calling: upcomingTeam1
I/flutter ( 8687):
I/flutter ( 8687): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 8687): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
I/flutter ( 8687): #1      _MainPageState._nextMatch (package:foci_dev/pages/main_page.dart:178:23)
I/flutter ( 8687): #2      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:992:19)
I/flutter ( 8687): #3      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1098:38)
I/flutter ( 8687): #4      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:184:24)
I/flutter ( 8687): #5      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:524:11)
I/flutter ( 8687): #6      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:284:5)
I/flutter ( 8687): #7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:256:7)
I/flutter ( 8687): #8      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:158:27)
I/flutter ( 8687): #9      GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:224:20)
I/flutter ( 8687): #10     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:200:22)
I/flutter ( 8687): #11     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:158:7)
I/flutter ( 8687): #12     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:104:7)
I/flutter ( 8687): #13     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:88:7)
I/flutter ( 8687): #17     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:267:10)
I/flutter ( 8687): #18     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:176:5)
I/flutter ( 8687): (elided 3 frames from dart:async)
I/flutter ( 8687):
I/flutter ( 8687): Handler: "onTap"
I/flutter ( 8687): Recognizer:
I/flutter ( 8687):   TapGestureRecognizer#acb21
```

If I interpret this correctly, it means that the upcomingTeam1 property of the upcomingMatch is unassigned. I tried converting the function to async and adding the await keyword in front of the query, but it didn't help.
Thanks for the answers in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the update inside your the `then` block so upcomingMatch will have a value:

```
void _nextMatch() {
  UpcomingMatch upcomingMatch;
  Firestore.instance
      .collection('football')
      .document("cMrD3OoOsWuzJmzlpfsr")
      .get()
      .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
        if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
          upcomingMatch = UpcomingMatch(
              documentSnapshot.data["nextTeam1"].toString(),
              documentSnapshot.data["nextTeam2"].toString());
          print(documentSnapshot.data["nextTeam1"].toString());
          print(documentSnapshot.data["nextTeam2"].toString());
        }
        if (upcomingMatch.upcomingTeam1.isNotEmpty &&
          upcomingMatch.upcomingTeam2.isNotEmpty) {
            Firestore.instance
            .collection("football")
            .document("cMrD3OoOsWuzJmzlpfsr")
            .updateData({
              "currentTeam1": upcomingMatch.upcomingTeam1,
              "currentTeam2": upcomingMatch.upcomingTeam2,
            });
        }
      });
}
```